# check value of 'number' html form input and validate only if higher then 0

Tags: javascript

Below is my vanilla js validation code. It works fine, but I am trying to add one more parameter specific to my '`number`' input field. I would like it to only validate if the user has entered a number higher then `0`, so `0` will not suffice as a correct input. i tried nesting another `if statement` within my validation function but continuously get errors in console and breaks correct working code.

```
function validateForm(){
    // var number = document.getElementById("number"); 
    var form = document.getElementById("form"), inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"), input = null, flag = true;
    for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        // if the value is not a valid number or it's less than or equal 0 
        if(isNaN(input.value) || +input.value <= 0) { 
            flag = false;
            input.focus();
            console.log("Please fill all the inputs (with numbers > 0)");
            break;
        }
    }
    return(flag);ß
}
```

*ie.* attempt does not work when nested.

```
   if (parseInt(number) > 0 && !isNaN(number))) {
        // console 
      }
   else {
        // console 
      }
```

Comment: Do try and avoid jamming a bunch of `var` declarations on a single line like that. It impedes clarity, *especially* when asking others for help.

Comment: Where did you put the last `if`? Inside the loop or outside it?

Comment: I would like to nest all validations within validateForm function

Comment: `price` is not an input inside the form???

Comment: Sorry the selector is 'number'. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your input has `type="number"`, You can use this condition

```
if (input.type == 'number' && +input.value <= 0) {
  // error, entered number less than or equal to 0
}
```